# how to store image url in oracle database and retrieve it through ejb

Tags: java

My project is an EJB. I want to store image in the oracle database. I understand its more efficient to store the file path in database and the images in a folder. My folder "images" is located in ejb. Please if the image is java.jpg, how do I construct the file path? I have tried both images/java.jpg and images\java.jpg and none worked.
The real path to the image location is "C:\Users\Kate\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Kate_Assig\Kate_Assig-ejb\images" and "Kate_Assig-ejb" is the ejb project and that's where the images folder that contains the images is.

The challenge I have right now is to store the file path in database. I have tried this option "..\images\java.jpg" and it didn't work. It didn't work because images are not displayed when I query the table from the client side.

The client is web application.

Comment: What is real path for images folder? ejb\images is strange.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm just a new Java student. Please if you have solution give because the deadline for submission is today. Real path is "C:\Users\Kate\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Kate_Assig\Kate_Assig-ejb\images"

Comment: This site is not intended to do students home work. We can help you to solve the problem yourself. But if you want just solution, good luck.

Comment: I am not asking for solution. I am only asking for suggestion. The project is working perfectly. Its just the images are not showing. If I wanted solution I won't keep night vigil developing this application. I only asked for how to create the url and not the code because my code is right

Comment: Ok, edit your question and add more information about your project structure and deployment. It is hard to answer when we miss crucial information. I can just guess that you have expanded war with ejb module, but the path is strange.

Comment: What do you want to do with these images? You wrote that you will store URL in database. Shall it be web application? If it is not web application, consider storing file path instead of URLs.

Comment: Yes please answer how this application is to be deployed

Comment: Another important information is how you access the URL. You said that it does not work. What does it mean? Do you open it in browser and receive 404 not found error? Or do you open Connection/URL in java code and it throws IOException. We need to know to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Let say that you stored image in some directory and its path in database and you have just JEB module, though you want to access images over web using URL. What you need to understand is that EJB does not provide web access. You have to create web module as well and configure it to serve your images.

There shall be servlet that accepts image identifier in parameter or in path. It will then load path from database, open the file and return it back. If you store the file in some public place within web module (not under WEB-INF) then you do not need to use database at all. The parameter / path could be constructed that it holds enough information to find and serve it.

There is some tutorial on web module by Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html Basicly you need to create a war file with following structure:

```
index.jsp
WEB-INF\
   classes\
   lib\
   web.xml
```

Directory `WEB-INF` is protected and browser cannot access it. It contains `classes` directory to store web module classes, `lib` folder for dependencies (ejb module jar, libraries) and `web.xml`. This file is important as it defines your servlets, filters and URL mappings.

You can study following samples to implement your solution that will serve images stored on filesystem:

- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/Sendworddocument.htm
- http://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-display-image-using-servlet

I hope that this will help you to proceed.

Comment: I need to thank you guys for your effort. I decided to relocate the image folder from ejb to the web application client. Hope my professor won't crucify me for that. I was thinking that ejb should serve clients, therefore it should be the appropriate place for the images. Thanks.

Comment: yes. My professor knows only two scores. Zero or 100%. So a better solution is welcomed.

Comment: I thought something different: http://stackoverflow.com/tour :-) Btw could you write your task setting?  You might misunderstood it.